# TypeScript: pass rejected promise as a parameter

Tags: typescript, promise

I have the following function signature:

```
public myCustomFunction(): Promise<string> {
// Insert code here
}
```

I'm interested in returning a **rejected** promise with error.
How can I create one? The promise should be **already rejected**, I'm not interested in creating a new promise with reject/success handlers.

Comment: [`Promise.reject()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)?

Comment: Perfect, looks like it's what I was looking for! Feel free to post your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a promise in a pre-rejected state using [`Promise.reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject):

> The `Promise.reject()` method returns a `Promise` object that is rejected with a given reason.

As that quote suggests, you can pass a reason as an argument.